# Is it harmful to add Conversion Linker tag in Tag Manager, even if website doesn't need it?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a multi-site set-up, using one Tag Manager container to post data to each website's respective Google Analytics account, based on the URL.

Some of the sites use Google Ads to run promotions etc, so I believe those sites require the addition of a 'Conversion Linker' tag to fire on all page views. However, I'm wondering whether that tag can be included by default without any harm, on sites that don't currently run campaigns?

Would this be wise? If not, I can always load it conditionally depending on the site URL, but I'd rather not have to manage that if it's 'fine' to just include the tag across the board, with no conditions.

Thanks

Comment: Harm what?  Accuracy of stats?   User experience?

Comment: I guess it will add _some_ weight to the page, even if small, which is acceptable. I guess by harmful I mean will it impact any of the other tags and, yes, impact accuracy of stats and/or UX?  If it just silently fails when not needed then that should be fine.